# подключиться к postgresql на виртуальной машине debian

Tags: postgresql, debian, vmware

У меня есть приложение на C#, стоящее на хосте, с которого я отправляю данные в БД postgresql, установленную на этом же компьютере.

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=superuser;Database=people;");
```

Теперь нужно отправлять в postgresql, установленную на виртуальной машине Debian 9 (на VMware 15). Что нужно для этого сделать? Надо как-то добавить виртуалку в локальную сеть? Даже не знаю, что гуглить.

Comment: Настроить сеть между виртуальной и физической машиной, настроить операционную систему виртуальной машины на работу с этой сетью, настроить PostgreSQL на приём соединений извне и прописать IP-адрес виртуальной машины вместо 127.0.0.1 в коде.

Comment: можно подробнее с настройкой ОС виртуальной на работу с этой сетью?

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05